# Error while trying to use OKBuck in my App

Tags: android, okbuck

I am getting the following error when trying to OKBuck to build my app.

```
The following resources were not found when processing 
Pair(//app:res_googleRelease#resources-symlink-tree, buck-
out/gen/app/res_googleRelease#resources-symlink-tree/res): 
RDotTxtEntry{idType=int, type=drawable, name=home_screen_gradient, 
idValue=0x00000000, parent=home_screen_gradient}

BUILD FAILED: //app:res_googleRelease failed with exit code 1:
generate_resource_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience using okbuck, this error maybe because resource (drawable, resId, etc) not found or there something error on your xml layout.

but, if you think you didnt miss anything. you can try :

```
./buckw clean
./buckw build [target]
```

sorry for bad english